# MATLAB: How to find number that meet certain condition and mark it as "0"?

Tags: matlab

For example,

```
A = [1 0 1 1 0 -1 0 1 -1]

for i = 1: length(A)
```

how to mark the number as "0" when `sum(A(1:i)) ~= 1 && sum(A(1:i)) ~= 0`?

and how to write the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A = [1 0 1 1 0 -1 0 1 -1]

%# create all sums from 1 through i
sa = cumsum(A);

%# in output: ith element is true if sum from 
%# 1 through the ith element in A is 0 or 1
output = ismember(sa,[0 1])

output = 
   1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: @user1205030: `output = A==0` returns `true` wherever `A` is zero.